# Realtime CSS edit plugin

Tags: javascript, html, css

Does anyone know of any JS libraries/plugins that can be added to a site to allow for modifying any CSS class/style on the page in realtime?

Comment: Tra JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ I think it will help.

Comment: is it for debug purpose ? , if yes use browsers tool , they all have them built in or avalaible as plugin . the lightest one i know is editCSS for FF, key F12 for IE, ...

Comment: are you looking for something like this http://jsfiddle.net/hamidlab/Lnnkv/1/ ? .... where user can change page CSS realtime.

Comment: Yes check: http://livejs.com and https://github.com/mechio/takana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, in fact, a live css editor (with the apt name of Live CSS Editor) by rukavina. It's a JQuery plugin and you can find a demo of it at http://rukavina.github.io/live-css-editor/demo/ . You can download this plugin on github at https://github.com/rukavina/live-css-editor.

Answer (score 1):

Define realtime !!!

I am assuming by realtime you mean you want to edit the css in the server directly so you wont have to edit it in local and upload it in server
You can

1. Use filezilla to edit files directly in server.
2. Upload a file-manager script which lets you edit files directly in server. http://www.hotscripts.com/category/scripts/php/scripts-programs/file-manipulation/file-management/

But then you will face another problem, users who have already opened your site will have css files cached in their browser. To solve that problem you can append GET queries for example:

```
style.css?v=1.1
style.css?v=1.2
```

This way you just have to change the version info and styles will be reloaded

Answer (score 0):

You could feed jQuery's .css() with changing variables

http://api.jquery.com/css/